# css placing of divs not proporciional

Tags: html, css

I want to make a mosaic of divs that is responsive.

My HTML is

```
<section>
    <div class="big margin-bottom">1</div>
    <div class="right margin-bottom">2</div>
    <div class="medium right">3</div>
    <div class="margin-right">4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</section>
```

and I made a version that works good in [1200 x 600](http://jsfiddle.net/26wev3fu/), but when I scale down to half ([800 x 400](http://jsfiddle.net/26wev3fu/2/)) it doesn't keep the proportions... what am I missing? I thought by using percentages it would resize properly.

```
.right {
    float: right;
}
.margin-bottom {
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.margin-right {
    margin-right: 1.1%;
}
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #ccf;                                   
}
div {
    float: left;
    height: 32%;
    width: 32.3%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.big {
    height: 64%;
    width: 66%;
}

.medium {
    height: 64.1%;
}
```

Comment: I didn't see any difference http://jsfiddle.net/26wev3fu/5/ (600 x 400) and http://jsfiddle.net/26wev3fu/4/ (1200 x 800)

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai if you look closer in the edges they are not matching in different sizes.

Comment: Are these elements going to be pictures?

Comment: Have you tried something called 'div.inline'

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif not sure what you mean?

Comment: It doesn't matter, ignore what I said lol, I tried adding something called 'div.inline' into your css and it didn't work..